# margin appears on both size when using skeleton css framework

Tags: css, frameworks, margin, dynamic-columns, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I've just installed skeleton framework to experience it.
i'm using 16 columns layout and i see that i have margins on left and right when i test it on iphone.

someone has an idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column margins for phones and other devices using [**media queries**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) in the CSS.

Skeleton uses margin-left:10px, and margin-right:10px on the columns by default so....

**An Typical example of setting the margins using Skeleton for an iPhone 5 would be:**

```
@media (max-width: 1136px) { .column, .columns {margin:0;} }
```

Comment: it doesn't help....
i just tried adding your code and a simple div to test it:

 @media (max-width: 1136px) {
 .container .column,
  .container .columns    {
   margin:0;
 }
 #test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
 }
   }


and put that div in sixteen columns container:

 <div class="container">
  <div class="sixteen columns">
   <div id="test"></div>
  </div>


 </div><!-- container -->

and i got a green box with margins on both sides on my iphone...

Comment: The solution provided is that to over-ride the margins set by Skeleton framework. If you are still getting margins then something else in your code is causing it and not the framework. Either link the site in question or narrow your question down by including CSS and HTML snippets.